# WordPress with WooCommerce .htaccess category redirect to external page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce

I want to add a category to a WooCommerce webshop. If that category is clicked, it needs to be redirected to an external webpage. For example if the following URL is visited:

website.nl/product-categorie/aanhangwagen-verhuur/

It should be redirected to example.com/

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

RewriteRule ^product-categorie/aanhangwagen-verhuur$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

```
Redirect permanent /product-categorie/aanhangwagen-verhuur/ http://example.com/
```